# Como borrar los datos que solo tienen 5 dígitos en un campo

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos días tengo una tabla que se llama Socio, esta tabla tiene los siguientes campos
Id,
Nombre,
Apellido,
Email,

estos campos tienen varios registros pero solo debo de borrar los que en el campo Email tenga 5 dígitos Ejemplo de los datos que se deben borrar 12345,abc12, esta tabla tiene 800 registros entonces no se como construir el query para eliminar solo los que tenga 5 dígitos en este campo alguien me puede ayudar a construir el delete?

Comment: **Haz una copia de tu tabla antes de ejecutar la siguiente sentencia**, _no me hago responsable de los resultados_. `DELETE Socio WHERE LENGTH(Email) = 5`

Comment: si me funciono asi muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok, te agregué la respuesta. Hace un rato no tuve tiempo de redactarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `LENGTH()` de `MySql`, la cual devuelve la cantidad de caracteres de una cadena de texto.

Puedes aprovecharla en la cláusula `WHERE`, de la siguiente manera.

```
DELETE Socio WHERE LENGTH(Email) = 5
```

Siempre **es importante hacer una copia de las tablas antes de ejecutar una sentencia como esta** ya que se eliminan los datos.